# How do I automate Management Token generation in Azure API MANAGEMENT?

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

[image]

The Azure APIM SAS Token gets expired every 30 days, is there an alternative approach to automate the entire flow of SAS TOKEN Generation to avoid plumbing work every 30 days?

Answer (score 0):

Direct management API should be used in very narrow cases, for most people it is recommended to use ARM REST API to manage APIM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/

ARM allows other authentication mechanisms as client id/secret, certificate, managed identity e.t.c.

Comment: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/getssotoken?api-version=2021-08-01  `. Did I find this API ref correct? , Are the management token and sso token the same? I found it in this [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/api-management-service/get-sso-token?tabs=HTTP)

Comment: What you're trying to use is Direct management API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/api-management-rest. But this is not the only way to manage APIM service. It is by far preferred to manage it via ARM like any other Azure service. Notice the difference in how requests look, when you're using direct API you're sending requests to <service-name>.management.azure-api.net, and you have to use SSO token. When you're using ARM you're sending request to management.azure.com and you can use any ARM supported authentication mechanisms.